# Matching text having HTML tags with RSpec and Capybara

Tags: html, testing, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using RSpec and Capybara to expect text containing HTML tags, like this:

```
expect(page).to have_css('#dom_id', :text => "Text with <b>HTML tags</b>", :visible => true, :count => 1)
```

When I run the automated test I get:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css('#dom_id', :text => "Text with <b>HTML tags</b>", :visible => true, :count => 1)
  expected to find visible css "#dom_id" with text "Text with <b>HTML tags</b>" 1 time but there were no matches. 
  Also found "Text with HTML tags", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

By simulating the test as a human (that is, manually browsing the page to display the text), I properly get the HTML-parsed `Text with <b>HTML tags</b>` output: "Text with **HTML tags**" (i.e. text with bolded "HTML tags").

How can I make the test to pass considering/matching the HTML tags within the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<b>` isn't text it's an element in the page so you can't verify it using the :text option.  If it's really important that the bold be tested you could something like

```
expect(page).to have_css('#dom_id b', exact_text: 'HTML tags')
```

If you really insist on doing what you're asking you could likely do it with JS in a filter block, something like

```
expect(page).to (have_css('#dom_id') do |el|
  el.evaluate_script('this.innerHtml') == 'Text with <b>HTML tags</b>'
end)
```

but I wouldn't recommend it as a normal use case.

Comment: Can you recommend to make the "inverse matching", meaning to remove the HTML tags from the `:text => "Text with <b>HTML tags</b>"`?

Comment: @Backo - You mean to do `text: 'Text with HTML tags'` ? Yes I would recommend that if you're trying to verify visible text on the page

Comment: And what about `expect(find('#dom_id', :visible => true, :count => 1)['innerHTML'].squish).to eq("Text with <b>HTML tags</b>")`? Would you recommend this?

Comment: @Backo No I would not because that defeats the retrying behavior

Comment: What do you mean with "defeats the retrying behavior"?

Comment: Capybara finders and matchers have built-in retry to deal with asynchronous page changes/updates. When you use RSpecs matchers (eq, etc) with Capybara elements you  lose that retrying